# Concat value of input element to a string using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to concatenate the value of the input element into a string in jquery

I am  having trouble concatenate the value of the input element to the end of the string.

Using just `companyString` or `#companyString` etc is not working

Below is my code

```
 $('#search').click(function() {
 $.getJSON('example.php?ol=searchname&name=' + '#companyString'});
```

Below is my html

```
Name: <input type="text" id="companyString" value=" ">
 <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need wrap the string with jQuery object of the input element.

```
 $('#companyString').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to take input box value is

```
$('#companyString').val();
```

For eg :

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('example.php?ol=searchname&name=' + $('#companyString').val();    ,function(data)
```

Comment: Nice answer with good example. Probably worth mentioning for readability's sake - where long strings are concerned, to store the value in a variable and use it in the `+ variableName` concatenation :)